# Vim: is there an equivalent of :tab that executes a command and splits (or vsplits)

Tags: vim

```
:[count]tab {cmd}
```

Executes a command and places the opened buffer (if any) in a new tab instead.

```
:tab b part-of-filename
```

Is a fast way to open a buffer in a new tab.

Is there an equivalent that does the same with a split or vertical split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:split +{cmd}` is supported to run a command on splitting.

However, this can't be used to select a buffer, for that do `:sbuffer` (`:sb`) and `:vert sb`